# Tikz: line ending between two rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf, line, flow-charts

I would like to connect the east point of the diamond with the midpoint between two rectangles (Phase 2, Phase 3) using the tikz library; see the picture, please.

Here is the sample code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=80pt,box/.style={rectangle,draw}] 

\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, aspect=3]

\node (dec)  [decision] {$A>B$};
\node (proc1) [box, below of=dec, yshift=-0.5cm] {Phase 1};
\node (proc2) [box, below of=proc1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Phase 2};
\node (proc3) [box, below of=proc2, yshift=-0.5cm] {Phase 3};

\draw [arrow] (dec) -- (proc1);
\draw [arrow] (proc1) -- (proc2);
\draw [arrow] (proc2) -- (proc3);
\draw [arrow] (dec) -| ([xshift=1cm, yshift=0cm]dec.east) |- coordinate[midway](proc3)(proc2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The main idea is to compute the midpoint of two rectangles: Phase2 and Phase 3.

Unfortunately, the resulted end point is the midpoint of the eastern edge of the rectangle Phase 2.

Thanks for your help.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Your flow chart I would draw on the following way:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
              > = Stealth,  
  node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
    start chain = going below,
     box/.style = {draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
decision/.style = {diamond, draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
                   align=center, aspect=3}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by ->}]
\node (dec)     [decision]  {$A>B$};
\node (proc1)   [box]       {Phase 1};
\node (proc2)   [box]       {Phase 2};
\node (proc3)   [box]       {Phase 3};
    \end{scope}
\draw [->]      (dec.east) --++ (1,0) |- ($(proc2.south)!0.5!(proc3.north)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- nodes are connected in chain
- arrows between nodes are drawn by macro `join`
- coordinate between last two nodes is calculated by `calc` chains
- in defining of image elements styles is used recent To*k*Z syntax, for positioning library `positioning.

[image]

Comment: @ Zarko: thanks for your interesting solution.

Comment: @justik, here is policy that you express your thankfulness by voting of answer ;-)

Comment: @ Zarko: Of course, with pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. While connecting two rectangles, the midpoint is computed:

```
\draw [arrow] (proc2) -- (proc3) coordinate[midway] (mid);
```

and connected with the diamond's eastern point:

```
\draw [arrow] (dec) -| ([xshift=1cm, yshift=0cm]dec.east) |- (mid);
```